# How to just continue with request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use BasicAuth with Asp.Net. That works so far. There is only one thing I can't figure out. Given the following code, how do I continue with the incoming request if the user is authenticated ?

It looks as if the BasicMiddleware has the needed next RequestDelegate. But how do I access it in the Run method ?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IHostingEnvironment env, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{...
 app.Run(async (context) =>
 {
     if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         await context.Authentication.ChallengeAsync();
      else
         wait ???
 });
  .....
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used Use instead of Run and it works.